# How can I prevent the privacy warning in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have Excel 2007. When I want to save a spreadsheet, I often see this message:

[image: Excel privacy warning]

I've seen this with macro spreadsheets (using the .xlsm extension) and with non-macro sheets (using the .xlsx extension).

How can I prevent this warning *every time* I save my spreadsheet?

Comment: It even popped up when I was *not* saving my spreadsheet! Aaargh!

Comment: Uncheck Remove personal information from file properties on save

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255584/be-careful-parts-of-your-document-may-include-personal-information-that-cannot-b

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Disable document inspector in the Trust Center.

*Note: picture may not be exact as I use Office 2010.*

[image: Excel Options]

Step by step instructions (for 2007):

1. Office orb
2. Excel options
3. Trust Center
4. Trust Center Settings...
5. Uncheck **Remove personal information from file properties on save**
6. OK
7. OK

Comment: Excellent! But **why oh why** do Microsoft make this so amazingly complicated?!

Comment: Step 4a. Privacy Options

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

> Office Orb > Excel Options > Trust Center/Trust Center Settings >
>   Document-specific Settings
>
> Uncheck "*Remove personal information from file properties on save*"

[image: 1]

Comment: I don't see this option. I see Office Orb > Excel Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings (new dialog): no Document-specific Settings. On the left side I see a list from Trusted Publishers to Privacy Options.

Comment: I guess you didn't check the link that I provided...

Comment: Indeed, I did not notice it. Thanks!