# How to paste from Excel with VBA macros (xlsm) to PowerPoint (pptx) without warning

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I teach using a combination of Excel and PowerPoint. I use an Excel workbook with a helper macro that makes it easy to display a cell's formula adjacent to that cell. I don't think it's directly relevant, but here it is:

```
'8/5/2006 Thanks to Maja Sliwinski and Beni Czaczkes
Function getformula(r As Range) As String
   Application.Volatile
   If r.HasArray Then
   getformula = "<-- " & " {" & r.FormulaArray & "}"
   Else
   getformula = "<-- " & " " & r.FormulaArray
   End If
End Function
```

In a workbook *without* macros (xlsx) I can select a chart and copy it with CTRL-C, then paste it into the PowerPoint slide with CTRL-V (or paste special to get several data and formatting options). But if I make a chart in this macro-enabled workbook (xlsm), then I can't easily paste it into PowerPoint. When I try, PowerPoint freezes/pauses because there is a warning from Excel that I should "Be careful" because the "document inspector may not remove all personal information". Sometimes I can get the pasting to take, but I haven't noticed a pattern if it takes two or three or four attempts.

How can I remove this warning so that I can get the behavior I want?

I should add that I can "Insert" the workbook as an object, but I would prefer the simplicity of cut-and-paste. As well, many times the workbook may have more than one table or chart, so I prefer to manually select each table or chart.

Comment: Why do you need this macro? Why not use `FORMULATEXT()`?

Comment: Upon further research, `FORMULATEXT()` was added in Excel 2013, so not having that version would be a pretty good reason not to use it. I can't reproduce this behavior in Office 2013, even if I copy your exact macro (comment and all) into a module.

Comment: @Kyle - Thanks! I didn't know about `FORMULATEXT()`. Does your inability to replicate this error mean that this is due to security settings on my computer? This occurs on both my (work-provided) laptop and classroom desktop. Is there something that I can change about the document inspector? Or about macro security settings.

Comment: I don't know. You can go to Options>Trust Center>Document Inspector and mess with the settings there and see if that helps. There is an option to check macros, so you could try unchecking that.

Comment: @Kyle - Thanks! I guess if I try to paste to PowerPoint, then Excel saves the workbook (at least a copy) and that gives the error. So it isn't the act of pasting, it is the warning itself that gums up everything. In Excel 2013 this is File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings... -> Privacy Options and uncheck "Remove personal information on save".

Comment: More here: http://superuser.com/questions/377583/how-can-i-prevent-the-privacy-warning-in-excel